# How to add a view whitout template?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a login view, but I see the same structure that in the rest of the web, I can see the menu and the navbar.

Can you help me with this? How can I remove these parts in the login view?

Route Code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('RDash')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$mdDateLocaleProvider', 'calendarConfig', '$breadcrumbProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $mdDateLocaleProvider, calendarConfig, $breadcrumbProvider) {

            $breadcrumbProvider.setOptions({
              prefixStateName: 'index',
              template: 'bootstrap3'
            });

            // For unmatched routes
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            // Application routes
            $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Title'
                }
            })
            .state('prueba', {
                url: '/prueba',
                templateUrl: 'templates/prueba.html',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Title'
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="RDash">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MasterCtrl" class="posicion-menu">
  <div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar">
        <li class="sidebar-main">
          <a ng-click="toggleSidebar()">
            <!--Dashboard-->
            <img class="logo" ng-src="img/logo.png" alt="Title Logo">
            <span class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#/section1">Section 1 <span class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#/section2">Section 2 <span class="menu-icon fa fa-search"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#/section3">Section 3 <span class="menu-icon fa fa-file-text-o"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Sidebar -->

    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div class="page-content">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div ui-view id="contenedor"></div>

      </div><!-- End Page Content -->
    </div><!-- End Content Wrapper -->
  </div><!-- End Page Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Login.html is empty.

I need the login view is empty, only whit the login form, and the rest of the website whit the navigation bar and the menu on the left.

[image: Actual View]
[image: Result whitout navbars]

Comment: In the MasterCtrl check the $stateProvider's state. If it is in login, set a flag that the template can use to hide or show the menu and navbar components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the menu and the navbar, then put them in the `ui-view`.

Otherwise, they will always stay.

Comment: But I have a lot of views. I can do a view only for the login??

Comment: Well you have 2 options : 1 - Create views and sub-views, so that you can chose which view has the menu (mother view) and which views haven't (child view) but it's a lot of code. Or 2 - create a modal to login your users.

Comment: Thanks! I have created 2 views, one with menu and other withot menu.

Comment: Nice, I think it's the best way to do it. Don't forget to put your subject as resolved !